# how can i run cygwin from vim

Tags: vim, cygwin, tlaps

The prover of TLA requires Cygwin, I want to run it (`tlapm.exe` for example) in Gvim, How can I start cygwin from a vimscript program

In the TLA toolbox, eval it as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/tlapm --toolbox 21 21 --isaprove -I C:\cygwin\usr\local\lib\tlaps\ C:\tla\Channel.tla
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke other executables from Vimscript with `:! cmd` or `call system(cmd)`. To run a Cygwin binary, you can invoke the command through the Cygwin Bash:

```
:echo system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "/usr/local/bin/tlapm --toolbox 21 21 --isaprove -I C:\cygwin\usr\local\lib\tlaps\ C:\tla\Channel.tla"')
```

or even directly (`C:\cygwin\bin\tlapm`). Note that the `C:\cygwin\...` arguments are better written in Cygwin path notation; the backslashes may need escaping or cause problems.